# Jenkins UI Output not visible till jobs completes

Tags: jenkins

Is there an option to display the jenkins job output while in progress.
If we run a Windows or Shell script all output only displays untill the job completes. Is there a STDOUT buffer or cache that holds the output?
The job is a simple grep of a log for specific text.
In windows or Linux the revision number shows within 1 minute of grepping the logs. In Jenkins it waits 17 minutes till the last line in the log is read before outputting to console log

Console Output

Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace /data00/jenkins/jobs/SVN_FIND_LINUX/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3137126077079530841.sh
+ date
Tue May 13 09:26:22 PDT 2014
+ gawk '-vRS=\n-+\n' '/r132570/ {print}'
+ svn log -v https://sub.company.com/svn/division-dev
r132570 | userid | 2014-05-07 06:05:12 -0700 (Wed, 07 May 2014) | 3 lines
Changed paths:
   M /Customer/company/G7/lag/Common/inilib/SACI_DIST.ini

Jira ID: JIRA-1414

- date
  Tue May 13 09:43:34 PDT 2014
  Notifying upstream projects of job completion
  Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Have you looked into the console?  I run several Jenkins jobs (both types of scripts) and the output is sent to the console when it is executed.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you are looking for? My understanding is that as part of jenkins job you are simply executing a shell script and you want its output to be displayed. But i am not clear where you want it to be displayed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins execute windows batch Path issue and redirected output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574044/jenkins-execute-windows-batch-path-issue-and-redirected-output)

Comment: Yes. The output will only show in the console log after the command completes not while it is in progress. This is different behavior when we run the grep in CMD windows  or Linux prompt. We did think it was a path problem but it seems the limitation was in Jenkins only since the path was verified.

Comment: See updated description

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins will print the line buffer to "Console Output" section when it meets a **newline** character on that line. If your line does not terminate, it will not be printed until it does.

Comment: Is there a way to send a newline in GREP the same way it works in a windows or Linux prompt for SVN Grep command? Or change to line by line search with CF LF

Comment: Not that I know of, but I am not an expert in that area